# How to insert data in to database on button click?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, post, insert

I have a modal which reads in values such as the code below. When i click on the submit button within the modal is it possible to insert values such as $row3['first_name'] etc. in to the database? I have researched this but I don't see much information on it as they mostly use text fields.

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-success hidden" id="request" data-toggle="modal" name="req" data-target="#basicModal">Request from Lender</a>
   </br></br>  

   <form action="" method="post">
<div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>           
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><?php
print $row3['title'] . ' from ' . $row3['first_name'] . ' ' . $row3['last_name'];
?></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Are you sure you want to borrow <b> 1 x <?php
print $row3['title'];
?></b> from <b> <?php
print $row3['first_name'];
?> <?php
print $row3['last_name'];
?></b> for <b id="total"></b> cogs? 
                    </br></br> You will be required to collect and return this item to <?php
print $row3['houseno'];
?> <?php
print $row3['address1'];
?> <?php
print $row3['postcode'];
?>.
                    </br></br> <?php
print $_GET[$from];
?> Your cogs will not be transferred to <?php
print $row3['first_name'];
?> until you have confirmed you wish to proceed following the lenders decision!</p>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success">Register</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
       </form>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to invoke a method, passing the values you want to insert into the database.

Example:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: How would i go about doing that? :S

Comment: Thanks - I ended up doing it like this though... 

if(isset($_POST['button1'])) { 
$q = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (keys) VALUES ('$values')")or die(mysql_error()); 
if($q) { 
echo "successful"; 
}else { 
echo "error"; 
} 
}